# How can I return a 404 status code by app.UseStatusCodePages?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

These days I am handling 404 Not Found by Asp.Net Core .

As we know, there are several ways to achieve this: app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects/app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute/app.UseStatusCodePages .

I have to choose the app.UseStatusCodePages for I need to localizer the page by URL.

For example:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/

The 'en-us' in URL just for deciding the language of the page.

Here is my code in startup.cs

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
            {
                string currentCulture = "";
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/').Length < 2)
                {
                    currentCulture = "en";
                }
                else
                {
                    string LanguageGet = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/')[1];
                    currentCulture = SupportedCultures.Find(X => X.Name == LanguageGet) == null ? "en" : SupportedCultures.Find(X => X.Name == LanguageGet).Name;
                }
                var redirectPath = "/" + currentCulture + "/Error/" + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectPath);
            });
```

Now it works.

However, after I input a URL(localhost:4387/en/123.html) which does not exist. The header shows a 302 status code in the Network of Chrome DevTools but not a 404 status code.

[image]

Well, when I input the URL(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/123.html) which does not exist, the header shows a right 404 status code in the Network of Chrome DevTools. It is just the right status code I need.

[image]

I searched about this on Google. Someone said I should add a ProducesResponseType in the controller, just like this:

```
public class OthersController : Controller
    {
        [Route("{culture=en}/Error/{code:int}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public IActionResult Error(int code)
        {            
            return View(code);
        }
    }
```

Well, it doesn't work any. I want to solve this because of SEO.

Here are all the source codes of this sample project in onedrive:https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtcqjirAlaGYiuUyWqy8gzpgPF9U1Q?e=8WTYln

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: If you enter the existing page address and the localized input is  `en`, do you want to display it as a 302 error or a 404 error?

Comment: @YongqingYu a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by replacing the code like this:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
        {
            var StringArray = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split("/");
            string currentCulture = "en";
            if (StringArray.Count() >= 2)
            {
                currentCulture = StringArray[1];
            }
            var newPath = "/" + currentCulture + "/Error/" + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = newPath;                
            await context.Next(context.HttpContext);
        });
```